# Specific `build` directory not added to Docker image

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have a repository with a directory structure like this

```
.
├── Dockerfile
├── README.md
├── frontend/
├── backend/
├── docs/
├── examples/
└── build/
```

The dockerfile is a simple ADD with no entrypoint:

```
FROM python:3.6-slim
WORKDIR /app

# Copy and install requirements.txt first for caching
ADD . /app
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir --trusted-host pypi.python.org -r backend/requirements.txt

EXPOSE 8200
WORKDIR /app/backend
```

My issue is that after `docker build -t myimage .`, the `build` folder is missing from the image.

I just ran an `ls` when verifying the image contents with `docker run -it myimage /bin/bash`, and the build folder is missing!

```
.
├── frontend/
├── backend/
├── docs/
├── examples/
```

Does anyone know why? How can I add modify my Dockerfile to add this folder into my image? All resources online say that `ADD . <dest>` should duplicate my current directory tree inside the image, but the `build` folder is missing...

Comment: Do you have a `.dockerignore` file that includes it?

Comment: Totally missed it... that was it, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Missed that there's a `.dockerignore` file in the repo that contains this folder. Whooooops, thank you @David Maze.